# How can I inexpensively determine if a column contains only NULL records?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a large table with 500 columns and 100M rows. Based on a small sample, I believe only about 50 of the columns contain any values, and the other 450 contain only NULL values. I want to list the columns that contain no data.

On my current hardware, it would take about 24 hours to query every column (`select count(1) from tab where col_n is not null`)

Is there a less expensive way to determine that a column is completely empty/NULL?

Comment: Will the columns be updated in some way? Are changes allowed?

Comment: The columns don't need to be updated. They can't be modified as part of the solution.

Comment: Main concern is performance, not writing dynamic sql to generate the query.

Comment: My first guess would be to look at sys.stats, but I'm pretty sure that, if SQL Server *does* store any data that will help you answer this question, it's in an internal-only table. (And I'm *pretty* sure it *doesn't* store anything that will help you.)

Comment: That sounds like a shocking database. You have my sympathy. :(

Comment: Wow, 5.8 GB wasted on just null-bitmaps!

Comment: Hence why I'm checking for said columns :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN column_1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0) column_1_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN column_2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0) column_2_count,
    ...
FROM table_name
```

?

You can easily create this query if you use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table.

**EDIT:**

Another idea:

SELECT MAX(column_1), MAX(column_2),..... FROM table_name

If result contains value, column is populated. It should require one table scan.

Comment: @user2161466 Note that this answer is not just about query creation, it allows you to deal with all columns at once instead of going through them one by one. That could mean a huge performance inprovement.

Comment: @Serge: It seems to me LukLed does answer te question being asked?? His suggestion processes all columns at once instead of one at a time...

Comment: @Mr47 I though counting only one column took 24hrs, but after a second read I see LukLed answer was appropriate.

Comment: @user2161466: If it would take 24h to execute 500 queries, it will probably take 24h/500 to execute this one query. It will still scan whole table, but it will do it in one iteration, not 500.

Comment: @LukLed: The SELECT MAX(col) ... had the best performance (500x). The SUM(CASE WHEN column_1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0) column_1_count was about (250x).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

**DDL:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.test2') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.test2

CREATE TABLE dbo.test2
(
      ID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , Name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , IsCitizen BIT NULL
    , Age INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.test2 (Name, IsCitizen, Age)
VALUES 
    ('1', 1, NULL),
    ('2', 0, NULL),
    ('3', NULL, NULL)
```

**Query 1:**

```
DECLARE 
      @TableName SYSNAME
    , @ObjectID INT
    , @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT 
      @TableName = 'dbo.test2'
    , @ObjectID = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(13) + ', [' + c.name + '] = ' + 
        CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 0 
            THEN '0' 
            ELSE 'CASE WHEN ' + totalrows + 
                 ' = SUM(CASE WHEN [' + c.name + '] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' 
        END
    FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) 
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT totalrows = CAST(MIN(p.[rows]) AS VARCHAR(50))
        FROM sys.partitions p
        WHERE p.[object_id] = @ObjectID
            AND p.index_id IN (0, 1)
    ) r
    WHERE c.[object_id] = @ObjectID
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ') + CHAR(13) + 'FROM ' + @TableName

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

**Output 1:**

```
SELECT
  [ID] = 0
, [Name] = 0
, [IsCitizen] = CASE WHEN 3 = SUM(CASE WHEN [IsCitizen] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
, [Age] = CASE WHEN 3 = SUM(CASE WHEN [Age] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM dbo.test2
```

**Query 2:**

```
DECLARE 
      @TableName SYSNAME
    , @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @TableName = 'dbo.test2'

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(13) + ', [' + c.name + '] = ' + 
        CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 0 
            THEN '0' 
            ELSE 'CASE WHEN '+
                 'MAX(CAST([' + c.name + '] AS CHAR(1))) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' 
        END
    FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) 
    WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ') + CHAR(13) + 'FROM ' + @TableName

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

**Output 2:**

```
SELECT
  [ID] = 0
, [Name] = 0
, [IsCitizen] = CASE WHEN MAX(CAST([IsCitizen] AS CHAR(1))) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
, [Age] = CASE WHEN MAX(CAST([Age] AS CHAR(1))) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM dbo.test2
```

**Results:**

```
ID          Name        IsCitizen   Age
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
0           0           0           1
```

Comment: On a single column, this gives about the same performance. Do you expect better performance in aggregate?

select count(1) from dbo.tab where col is not null -- 1:07

SELECT
col = COUNT(CASE WHEN ISNULL(CAST(col AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '') = '' THEN 1 END)
FROM
dbo.tab -- 1:08

Comment: @Devart: I'm not the downvoter but some explanation of why this is better would be interesting. Always best not to just give the answer but help people learn. :)

Comment: Not my downvote but it should be `IS NULL THEN 1` right? Also there would be good with a explanation on what you have done here. I used your query on a table to see what it actually does but it would be better if you could explain that and also explain why this would improve the performance compared to what already is in the question.

Comment: @Chris. Your are right :). In these queries we are receiving the list of columns and making a dynamic query for a table with a arbitrary structure. For the columns that initially can't have NULL values `c.is_nullable = 0`, we do not make any validations - as a result, we increase the execution speed. Afterwards, we use the aggregate function SUM in order to count the amount of the NULL values. Then, we compare the resulting value with the overall amount of strings. In the second variant we possible to use MAX.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if colums idexing will help you reach some performance improve

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IndexName ON dbo.TableName(ColumnName)
WHERE ColumnName IS NOT NULL;
GO
```

Comment: I considered this, but it takes as long to create an index on a column as it does to query it for nulls.

Comment: But there is still a benefit. you are indexing just once, but you can query than as many times as you wish

Comment: I would have to create an index on every column though, right? I left out some context in my question which is that I need this process to be repeatable on an un-indexed version of the table.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL server query to get the list of columns in a table along with Data types, NOT NULL, and PRIMARY KEY constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418527/sql-server-query-to-get-the-list-of-columns-in-a-table-along-with-data-types-no)

Run SQL in best answer of above questions and generate a new query like below.

`Select ISNULL(column1,1), ISNULL(column2,1), ISNULL(column3,1) from table`

Answer (score 0):

500 Columns?!

Ok, the right answer to your question is: normalize your table.

Here's what happening for the time being:

You don't have an index on that column so SQL Server has to do a full scan of your humongous table.

SQL Server will certainly fully read every row (it means every columns even if you're only interested in one).

And since your row are most likely over 8kb... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Seriously, normalize your table and if needed split it horizontally (put "theme grouped" columns inside separate table, to only read them when you need them).

**EDIT:** You can rewrite your query like this

```
select count(col_n) from tab
```

and if you want to get all columns at once (better):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(column_1) column_1_count,
    COUNT(column_2) column_2_count,
    ...
FROM table_name
```

Comment: If it has 100M records, it sounds to me like it's already in production use. Refactoring is not always easy in that case.

Comment: Sometime you have to make drastic changes to keep the system usable.

Comment: This is a table provided by a data provider on a periodic basis. The code I'm writing is to clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

You would not need to 'count' all of the 100M records. When you simply back out of the query with a TOP 1 as soon as you hit a column with a not-null value, would save a lot of time while providing the same information.

Answer (score 0):

If most records are not null maybe you can mix some of the approach suggested (for example check only nullable fields) with this:

```
if exists (select * from table where field is not null)
```

this should speed up the search because exists stops the search as soon as condition is met, in this example a single not null record is enough to decide the status of the field. 
If the field has an index this should be almost instant.

Normally adding top 1 to this query is not needed because the query optimizer knows that you do not need to retrieve all the matching records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this stored procedure to the trick You need to provide the table name you wish to query note that if you'll pass to procedure the @exec parameter = 1 it will execute the select query

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SELECT_NON_NULL_COLUMNS] ( @tablename varchar (100)=null, @exec int =0)
 AS BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF @tablename IS NULL
          RAISERROR('CANT EXECUTE THE PROC, TABLE NAME IS MISSING',16 ,1)
                      ELSE
    BEGIN
          IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #table
          DECLARE @i VARCHAR (max)=''
          DECLARE @sentence VARCHAR (max)=''
          DECLARE @SELECT VARCHAR (max)
          DECLARE @LocalTableName VARCHAR(50) = '['+@tablename+']'
          CREATE TABLE  #table  (ColumnName VARCHAR (max))
          SELECT @i+=
          ' IF EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 '+column_name+' FROM '  +@LocalTableName+' WHERE ' +column_name+
               ' '+'IS NOT NULL) INSERT INTO #table VALUES ('''+column_name+''');'
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name=@tablename
                INSERT INTO #table
                EXEC (@i)
                 SELECT @sentence = @sentence+' '+columnname+' ,' FROM #table                  
         DROP TABLE #table                 
                IF @exec=0
                      BEGIN
                            SELECT 'SELECT '+ LTRIM (left (@sentence,NULLIF(LEN (@sentence)-1,-1)))+
                                        +' FROM ' +@LocalTableName
                END
                ELSE
                      BEGIN 
                            SELECT @SELECT=  'SELECT '+ LTRIM (left (@sentence,NULLIF(LEN (@sentence)-1,-1)))+
                                              +' FROM '+@LocalTableName
                    EXEC (@SELECT)
                END
 END
 END
```

Use it like this:

```
EXEC [dbo].[SP_SELECT_NON_NULL_COLUMNS] 'YourTableName' , 1
```