# T-SQL: how do I query a table that results in a list of the fields that have NULLS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null

I'm looking to set up an array of data quality scripts on a new set of data that my group is getting. One of the issues I'd like to keep track of is maintaining a list of fields that contain `nulls`. Some fields that's ok, others it is not, although we don't want to block the `bulk insert` because we've not allowed certain fields to `null`.

Example:

```
SELECT [columns]
FROM [TABLE] T
WHERE [columns] CONTAINS NULLS
```

Comment: So what's the question again? It sounds like you just want to know the fields which can't be null in which case you could query the system tables for which columns are not nullable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204684/query-to-check-whether-a-column-is-nullable  or do you really want to know specific table statistics to see if a column has allowed a Null or not? which could be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852021/how-can-i-inexpensively-determine-if-a-column-contains-only-null-records  Either way this seems like a duplicate question.

Comment: More like the second link but I just want the results to show the name of the field if it contains a NULL in the data. These fields allow for nulls but we ideally don't want any nulls in them.

Comment: knowing that a column has 'illegal' values is not very useful for a data quality script.  It doesn't contain the information that you need to repair the problem, or context for what caused it.  I'd suggest triggers writing bad rows to audit tables.  With the complete record, you can actually hunt down the source of your troubles and fix it there.

Comment: Well...if the data you are modeling is such that it shouldn't allow NULL in a certain column...perhaps you should not allow NULL in that column. Maybe you should do your bulk insert to a staging table instead of directly into the target table.

Comment: @Greenspark We're getting the data from a vendor. If there's a null in these fields it's their fault and we want to make sure they are aware of that. We have to capability to audit and correct the nulls but it's taxing, thus why we outsourced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this in a function to loop thru all of the columns and see if there is a count of null values in the table. The code is kind of brute force but it would work.

```
declare @tablename nvarchar(255) = 'schema.tablename'

declare @results table (ColumnName nvarchar(255))

/* Declare the Variables to be used in the cusor*/
declare @column_name nvarchar(255)


/* Declare the cursor and the value set that will be used*/
declare tbl_Crawler cursor
    for SELECT name FROM sys.columns 
        WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tablename)

/* Make the Cursor Available*/
open tbl_Crawler

/*Load the first row into the variables (must match sequence in cursor select)*/
fetch next from tbl_Crawler
    into @column_name

/*Creates While loop that will run until the curor is empty*/
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin

/*statement to be run every loop of the cursor*/

    DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)

    declare @counts int

    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT @cnt=COUNT(*) FROM '+@tablename+' WHERE '+ @column_name + '  is null'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@cnt int OUTPUT',  @cnt=@counts OUTPUT


    if (isnull(@counts,0) > 0)
        insert into @results 
        select @column_name

/*Loads the next row of records into the variables (must match sequence in cursor select)*/
    fetch next from tbl_Crawler
        into @column_name
    end
/*Release the cursor so that it is not retained in memory*/
close tbl_Crawler
deallocate tbl_Crawler

/* if in function return @results*/
    select * from @results
```

Comment: You ought to wrap the table and column name variables in [`QuoteName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid issues with "funny" names, e.g. a column named `Shoe Size` with a space.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. The code does leave a little to be desired.

Answer (score 2):

This is slow and ugly, but short of buying a tool from RedGate (et al.), you might be able to modify it with an ISNULL(@column,'PICK ME') to search for your nulls...

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX), @Column NVARCHAR(100), @Table NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Search NVARCHAR(100)
SET @Search = 'PICK ME'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Results2','U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.#Results2

CREATE TABLE #Results2(Table_Name VARCHAR(100), Column_Name VARCHAR(100))

DECLARE Col CURSOR FOR
SELECT Table_Name, Column_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION

OPEN Col
FETCH NEXT FROM Col INTO @Table, @Column
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @Query = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM '+QUOTENAME(@Table)+' WHERE '+QUOTENAME(@Column)+'='''+@Search+''')
                    SELECT '''+@Table+''','''+@Column+''''

    INSERT INTO #Results2
    EXEC sp_executesql @Query
    FETCH NEXT FROM Col INTO @Table, @Column
END
CLOSE Col
DEALLOCATE Col

SELECT * FROM #Results2
```