# I need a query to bring the query I mentioned below

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

```
SELECT table_name, 
       column_name, 
       data_type, data_length
  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
 WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE'
```

I need a query to get this query.

Comment: What do you mean by a query to get a query?

Comment: By the looks of it he probably means a function to run the query and get the results in whatever language he is using to program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select "SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length 
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE'" from dual;
```

Comment: my TL told me that there is a function to bring the properties of the table. if we dont know the size of the table.. can u say that?

Comment: `select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name='MYTABLE';`

Comment: Can we obtain output a query from a query?

Comment: the output must be this? what query we want to write?

SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'TEST1';

Comment: what r those queries? will u plz tell me

Comment: First, the query that I wrote in the comments, and when you have the column names - you can use them to make your second query which is, I guess, to fetch values from that table.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning.

I think your question may have been answered on stackoverflow here already: [SQL server query to get the list of columns in a table along with Data types, NOT NULL, and PRIMARY KEY constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418527/sql-server-query-to-get-the-list-of-columns-in-a-table-along-with-data-types-no)

Please have a look, don't just want to copy and paste someone else's answer

Comment: the output must be this? what query we want to write?

 SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'TEST1';