# Select columns, but casting all columns of given type

Tags: sql

I need something that is the logical equivalent of

```
select cast(* as numeric IF data_type='decimal') from table_name
```

I didn't know how to do that, so i'm trying to reduce it into two steps:

```
select * from table_name where data_type!='decimal'

select cast(* as numeric) from table_name where data_type='decimal'
```

But I realized I don't know how to do that, either. I can find the list of column names that are decimal thanks to SO, but as this is a batched process, i can't split this into two steps

Is what I'm trying to do possible? I just want to get a set of columns, but if they're decimal, cast them as double.

Thanks!

Comment: If the only reason for using SELECT * is laziness, then forget it and write out the select with each column name, and casts on the appropriate columns.  If it's for another reason, then you can probably do what you want with dynamic sql and the information schema views, but it will be much more research and coding than just writing out the select statement as I described above.

Comment: You can't cast the whole table like this.  have to do each column.

Comment: @TabAlleman well at some threshold well below several hundred columns (this use case) laziness == productivity :) and no I don't control their schema. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @imsoconfused . . . You do this type of operation using the metadata tables and dynamic SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ah got it, thanks. Given that my requirement is to pass the command untouched into SqlCommand.CommandText whose value is restricted to "Transact-SQL statement or a stored procedure", I am assuming this is not possible then, based on your vocabulary (sorry, know nothing about SQL).

Comment: With several hundred columns, I think you'll still probably solve your problem faster by ctrl-v pasting CAST() code into your select statement (which you can automatically generate in SSMS), than you would trying to create a dynamic sql/meta data solution.   But it can be done.

Comment: wrt your response to Gordon, you can wrap the whole meta-data/dynamic SQL solution in stored proc, so yes, it's still a possible solution for you.

Comment: @TabAlleman yeah it's not a db under our control so I was looking for a generic solution. I already suggested they implement the stored proc and pass that command in to us. Thanks

Comment: If this is used in a SQLCommand, then it must be part of a custom front-end.  Why don't you do the casting there?

Comment: @TabAlleman it's a custom front end, but it's a direct pass-through. unless you're suggesting i build a SQL parse tree and rewrite the SQL

Comment: @imsoconfused What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: @zaratustra SQL Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to explicitly cast each column like this:

```
SELECT CAST(Col1 AS INT),CAST(Col2 AS INT)..
FROM Table
```

Comment: thanks. Is this a limitation in the SQL grammar/description or would creating a feature request for this be productive? This is specific to SQL Server btw in case there are implementation-specific features available

Comment: @imsoconfused:- I dont think that this is a limitation rather a feature provided which in my opinion is correct and works as required!

Answer (score 3):

Or, you could create a function as follows (credit goes to poster listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418527/sql-server-query-to-get-the-list-of-columns-in-a-table-along-with-data-types-no)):

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[udf_getColumnDataType]    Script Date: 8/4/2014 10:59:23 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


/***************************************************************************
Code stolen from here:
http://bit.ly/1v26PmM
****************************************************************************/
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_getColumnDataType] (@TableName varchar(64), @ColumnName varchar(64) )
RETURNS varchar(64)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @DataType VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @DataType = 
    t.Name --'Data type'
FROM    
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
    WHERE
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
    and c.name = @ColumnName
    return @DataType
END
```

You then can check each column and cast accordingly.   Just pass the table name and the column name (as string) and it will return it to you.

```
Select iif(
    dbo.udf_getColumnDataType('your table name', 'your column name') ='decimal',
    cast(your_column_name as numeric), 
    your_column_name
) as col1
from your_table_name
```

I was trying to create this on SQL Fiddle, but seems like I can't create functions on their page.  It worked for me while testing in SQL Server 2012.  Hopefully, it's not a long route for you, but worth posting.

Comment: thanks, @AndriyM for the edit; I got carried away with trying to give a complete answer.  LOL