# ASP.net MVC - get data from SQL Server without knowing the data-structure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, csv

I would like to know how I can get data from SQL Server tables into my ASP.net MVC application without knowing the data-structure in advance.

Example:

- a user uploads a `.csv` file into the application with an unknown data structure (can be 3 fields can be 50 fields with varying data types)
- the `.csv` file gets stored into a SQL Server table
- now I want the application to be able to display the data from these uploads in e.g. a HTML table without having to use a hardcoded model

Is it possible to display the data using a connection string and e.g. LINQ to SQL or EF?  Best case would be where I can dynamically assign table names etc. into queries.

The models will still be used to access data belonging to the application logic, it's just the displaying of data from user-uploads that is not clear to me at this time.

Comment: So do you actually want your application to create the database table tha matches the csv structure? Or are you just wanting to store the data in a table - in which case you could explore object serialisation?

Comment: After user-upload of a csv-file a SQL-server-table gets created corresponding the fields and datatypes of the uploaded csv-file.

Comment: Both LINQ to SQL and EF are object-relational mappers- intended to be used with known object types to map to tables that are known to exist. What you are trying to do is completely possible however I would look at persuing your own implementation with ADO.NET / Stored Procedures

Comment: the uploaded csv-files can be larger sets (5 million+ rows) but would not relate - for the time being - to other tables.

Comment: Providing there is no validation on the insert logic, you could use this approach after programatically creating the table with .net - it'd be much faster - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Comment: @Carl okay, I am new to ASP.net MVC and was wondering what the bounderies are in using LINQ / EF for this purpose.

Comment: adding a new table every time a new csv is uploaded does't sound like a good approach, you might want to consider saving the csv files and serving them later when required.

Answer (score 0):

EF and Linq2Sql will always require you to have a existing model associated to a database table.

If you really need that "dynamic" query, you can use a micro-ORM like [dapper.Net](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#execute-a-query-and-map-it-to-a-list-of-dynamic-objects) to return your query to a `dynamic` type.

This solution won't save you from having generate the select sql query, by retrieving the list of fields from the table. Maybe you can use the sys tables from sql server (if that is the data base) for that. Like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418527/sql-server-query-to-get-the-list-of-columns-in-a-table-along-with-data-types-no)