# SQL Server query to get data type for all columns in table?

Tags: sql-server

I have this SQL Server 2012 query that I am running in SSMS:

```
SELECT name, max_length, precision, scale, is_nullable 
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.testtable')
```

It is returning what I want:

[image]

However, I would like to add the data type of the column in this query, so that it looks like what I see in the object explorer. Any thoughts on how to add the data type?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL server query to get the list of columns in a table along with Data types, NOT NULL, and PRIMARY KEY constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418527/sql-server-query-to-get-the-list-of-columns-in-a-table-along-with-data-types-no)

Comment: One google search for "SQL Server query column data types" would have gotten you an answer.

Comment: Thanks @vzwick, that worked! I didn't understand that I would need to get data type from sys.type.

Comment: @a1234 the ways of SQL Server are mysterious, sometimes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT c.name,
       c.max_length,
       c.precision,
       c.scale,
       c.is_nullable,
       t.name
  FROM sys.columns c
  JOIN sys.types   t
    ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
 WHERE c.object_id    = Object_id('dbo.testtable')
```

Answer (score 32):

Here are a couple of options:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'YourTable'
```

or

```
exec sp_help 'YourTable'
```

Comment: I can confirm the first command works using PgAdmin 4.13 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.3.1. The second command (exec sp_help) only runs for me on MSSMS but not PgAdmin.