# LINQ Query Error : how can I precisely identify which field is causing this error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

When this error happens in the LINQ Query, how can I precisely identify which field is causing error ?

> MethodName : get_Int32. Error : System.InvalidCastException: Unable to
> cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'. at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32() at
> lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext ,
> Int32[] , ResultCoordinator ) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.QueryingEnumerable1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable1
> source) at ..

My LINQ Query is pretty simple.

```
return dbContext.SomeTable.Where(x => x.KeyValue == keyValue).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here is the "real trouble". My table has 300+ fields.

It will be nice if there is an elegant solution to precisely identify the column that is causing this error. Please advise.

Comment: If that's a table and `KeyValue` is a column in it, it will have a fixed type. You need to share more details, what's the return type of your method? Types of `x.KeyValue` and `keyValue`.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to map string (varchar, char, etc.) field to `int` property. I'm afraid, the only way to fix this is to figure out invalid mapping. In case of 300+ fields the only advice is to comment all properties except, say, first 10, and try to fetch the data. In case of success, fetch next 10 props, etc.

Comment: That's exactly my issue. Out of 300+ fields, how can I nail it, which field is causing this issue. I wish there is some kind of logging/debugging in LINQ/Entity Framework which can write the field name that is causing this mapping error.

Comment: Look at the CREATE TABLE. Look at the property definitions. Compare them one by one.

Comment: here is a command which [gets all names and types of your table as a list in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146316/sql-server-query-to-get-data-type-for-all-columns-in-table). You can use reflection to do the same with your mapping class. Then print both lists side by side. This of course if you are looking for a little more automated way of analysis

Comment: how many columns are of type string in your table? and how many are of type int in your class? this should already narrow down the search space

Comment: That's right. We pulled that record from SQL and visually seeing if there is any issue. I am really looking for some "automated" solution which will precisely identify the field causing this mapping error. When LINQ is throwing this cast exception, I wish it adds the field name in the "Inner Exception Details".