# How to I extract a list of columns from a table in sql

Tags: sql, database

I am looking for a way to enlist the name and the number of columns in a table using sql, any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Oracle is DESC tableName, but you need to specify in the question....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL server query to get the list of columns in a table along with Data types, NOT NULL, and PRIMARY KEY constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418527/sql-server-query-to-get-the-list-of-columns-in-a-table-along-with-data-types-no)

Answer (score 0):

The standard `information_schema.columns` table should be available in most [rdbms](/questions/tagged/rdbms)s, so you could query it:

```
SELECT   table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, COUNT(*)
FROM     information_schema.columns
GROUP BY table_catalog, table_schema, table_name
```