# Query does not update the table

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am using stored procedure to complete the update query and I have set the messagebox to show when the query executes successfully. When I click the button the messagebox pops up but the table is not updated. I run the same query in SQL Server it updates the table but cannot update via the c#

I have already tried the same code in SQL Server the code works fine. Messagebox pop up when the command is executed

```
if (IsUpdate)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
                txtCustomerName.Enabled = false;

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ApplicationSettings.ConnectionString()))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_customer_updateProducts", con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", Contact);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", address);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAN", PAN);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAT", VAT);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", CustomerName);
                        con.Open();

                        try
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(CustomerName);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            MessageBox.Show("Customer Updated Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            this.Close();
                            CustomerRecordForm crf = new CustomerRecordForm();
                            crf.Show();
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is the code of stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_customer_updateProducts]
(
@Contact varchar,
@Address varchar,
@PAN varchar,
@VAT varchar,
@CustomerName varchar
)
as
begin
    update [dbo].[CustomerInfo]
    set [ContactNo]=@Contact,
        [Address]=@Address,
        [PAN]=@PAN,
        [VAT]=@VAT
    where [CustomerID] = (select CustomerID from CustomerInfo where CustomerName=@CustomerName)
end
```

Comment: Change it to `WHERE [CustomerId] IN ( SELECT CustomerId FROM... )` instead of `WHERE [CustomerId] = ( SELECT CustomerId FROM ... )`.

Comment: still getting the same bug

Comment: That said, you might want to consider changing the sproc's `UPDATE` query to use an `INNER JOIN` instead of `WHERE IN`, or use an initial query to set a `@customerId` variable as that might be easier to understand and lets you indicate error conditions where there's zero rows or more than 1 row that match` @CustomerName`.

Comment: but i have the record in same table so why use inner join

Comment: Why are you looking up `CustomerID`? If that's the primary key of your table then you should be passing `@CustomerID` into your stored procedure. Passing in `@CustomerName` and looking that up as you are doing could lead to two (or more) rows getting blatted with the same information.

Comment: You should replace the where condition to `where CustomerName = @CustomerName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign length to varchar data type else it will take only one character.
Please check below query.

```
DECLARE @Contact varchar

SET @Contact = 'CONTACT'

SELECT @Contact Contact
```

You need to check every column data type and its length.
Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2418665/7009448).

If you know the customer ID then please send customer id instead of customer name as a parameter, which will really help to you as well as SQL Server also.

Please check below updated stored procedure.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_customer_updateProducts]
(
    @Contact varchar(100), -- You need to define length
    @Address varchar(2000),
    @PAN varchar(50),
    @VAT varchar(50),
    @CustomerName varchar(50) -- If you know the customer ID then please send customer id instead of customer name.
)
as
begin

    SET NOCOUNT ON; -- Please use SET NOCOUNT ON. It will little help in performance.

    UPDATE [dbo].[CustomerInfo]
    SET [ContactNo] = @Contact,
        [Address] = @Address,
        [PAN] = @PAN,
        [VAT] = @VAT
    WHERE CustomerName = @CustomerName -- You can directly use customer name in where condition.

end
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the query and input share by you, there is one modification suggested, as of now you are passing `@CustomerName` to the procedure, now either you already manage at the time of `insert` that no duplicate name records are inserted in your table, or this is definitely a bug comes to you in production.

Now come to your current query part, as you posted `CustomerName` from front end so on basis of this name select your `id` and save it in a variable, which is later on used to update your record.

```
declare @Id int
set @Id = (select CustomerID from CustomerInfo where CustomerName=@CustomerName)

 update [dbo].[CustomerInfo]
    set [ContactNo]=@Contact,
        [Address]=@Address,
        [PAN]=@PAN,
        [VAT]=@VAT
    where [CustomerID] = @id
```

For debugging purpose you may return this `id` from procedure and save it in your code to check whether exactly which id is taken as for updation.